# Unable to deploy firebase project dependent on grpc library

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cli

I am getting an error while trying to deploy friendly-pix web application using Firebase-CLI. Can anyone help me with this issue?

`node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403): https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.10.0/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown.tar.gz`

`node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.10.0 and node@10.2.1 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)`

`node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.10.0/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown.tar.gz`

`node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.10.0 and node@10.2.1 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)`

Comment: What version of the firebase cli are you using?

Comment: @DougStevenson The version is 3.19.0